# Hungary visa expiring soon, but passport given to UK embassy for visa. Worried

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, passports, indian-citizens

My Hungary visa ends September 30, and I need an extension. My passport has been given to the UK embassy for stamping a student visa, and the last day they can return it is on the 29th. My ticket for the UK is booked for October 15. If I take my passport back for extending the Hungarian permit, it will take a month and I will miss out on the UK visa. What do I do? I'm an Indian citizen.

Comment: You question is getting close votes because people think it's a better fit on Expatriates. Sometimes if you flag the question, you can ask that it be migrated to [Expatriates.se]. I think it's also unclear. When did you send in the UK application. Have you had any updates?